# Speed up SUM Billion record on PostgreSQL

Tags: postgresql

I want discuss about PostgreSQL database. I have almost 5 Billion record on table called "invoices"
there store balance like this :

```
id | account |   type   | amount | current_balance
1       A        TOPUP     1000         1000
2       A        USAGE      -1   |       999
3       A        USAGE      -1   |       998
... more 5 billion record
```

all on record of account A have 5 Billion record, every transaction is SUM field Amount then store to current_balance, now every data added the query take more time (almost 30 second). I want to adjust speed the query, i have try add index on id and amount but not work. Should i change the schema and the flow ? or have any efficient idea ?

The query i used to calculate current balance

```
 SELECT SUM(Amount) FROM invoices WHERE account='A';
```

Query to insert for example on record id 3 :

```
INSERT INTO table_name (account, type, amount, current_balance)
VALUES ("A", "USAGE", "-1", SELECT SUM(Amount) FROM invoices WHERE account='A');
```

Then update for record id 3 :

```
UPDATE invoices set current_balance = (SELECT SUM(Amount) FROM invoices WHERE account='A' AND id <= '3')
```

doing every data insert like record id 3, insert and then update

Comment: Can you include the query you are trying to run against this table?

Comment: ok, i have edited the question

Comment: Which Postgres version are you using? What kind of hardware are you running on (number of harddisks, number of CPUs, memory). Btw: for that query, an index on `(account, amount)` would be necessary, not on "id and amount".

Comment: Is there an index on `account`?

Comment: yes, i have add index on all field on the table, but still same

Comment: You should define a trigger on INSERT/UPDATE so that on each new transaction you update `current_balance` for the given account - and it will always be actual. Then when doing SELECT you do not need to SUM because the balance has already been calculated by the last INSERT/UPDATE. However, if you have too many transactions/sec (per account) they will compete to lock the `current_balance` when updating it ...

Comment: Are you calculating the balance in one query and then updating/inserting the new row in a different query? Please show us *all* the queries you run on this table.

Comment: yes, it's different query after i'm insert the data then update the current balance